# Value of variable returned is incorrect after looping through multiple data table pages

Tags: javascript, html-table

Im fairly new to JS would appreciate any insight/ help.
I have a data table with multiple pages that can be navigated with a button and doesn't change the URL. I have made a simple for loop that returns the values correctly if I was to go through each page individually one by one.However when I implement it into a loop, the value returned seems to be the sum of the first page * remainidng pages.

The simple for loop will return:
Page 1: 50
Page 2: 49
Page 3: 10
Which is correct.

```
var table = document.querySelector("tbody");
let nextDay = 0;
let thirdDay = 0;
let tooLong = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  var currentRow = table.rows[i];
  var date1 = currentRow.cells[11].innerText;
  date1 = date1.substr(0,10);
  var date2 = currentRow.cells[10].innerText;
  date2 = date2.substr(0,10);
  date1 = new Date(date1.split('/')[2], date1.split('/')[1] - 1, date1.split('/')[0]);
  date2= new Date(date2.split('/')[2], date2.split('/')[1] - 1, date2.split('/')[0]);
  var Difference_In_Time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
      
  // To calculate the no. of days between two dates
  var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  if(Difference_In_Days === 1){
    nextDay++;
  }else if(Difference_In_Days === 2){
    thirdDay++;
  }else{
    tooLong++
  }
}
 console.log("Arrived Next Day: "+ nextDay);
```

When I implement it into a while loop I get:
Pages 1-3:150 when it should be 109.

```
let nextDay = 0;
let thirdDay = 0;
let tooLong = 0;
function calcDates(){
  var table = document.querySelector("tbody");
    for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
      var currentRow = table.rows[i];
      var date1 = currentRow.cells[11].innerText;
      date1 = date1.substr(0,10);
      var date2 = currentRow.cells[10].innerText;
      date2 = date2.substr(0,10);
      date1 = new Date(date1.split('/')[2], date1.split('/')[1] - 1, date1.split('/')[0]);
      date2= new Date(date2.split('/')[2], date2.split('/')[1] - 1, date2.split('/')[0]);
      var Difference_In_Time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
          
      // To calculate the no. of days between two dates
      var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
      if(Difference_In_Days === 1){
        nextDay++;
      }else if(Difference_In_Days === 2){
        thirdDay++;
      }else{
        tooLong++
      }
    }
}
pageNum = 1;
while(pageNum <= 3){
  const nextPage = document.getElementById("table_id_next");
  calcDates()
  pageNum++
  nextPage.click()
}
console.log("Arrived Next Day: "+ nextDay);
```

The only reason I can think of is that the data table is not updating.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend checking out [mcve] and [ask]. That will help you get the best answers for your problem. Right now, you don't show anything that has to do with paging, nor an example table. Just some code that does something with dates